# The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication

The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

```
Container(
              width: 54,
              height: 54,
              decoration:BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                    user.profilePhotoUrl,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

please helpmee

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68058364/flutter-the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-s)

Answer (score 0):

Dart offers null safety to the users.

For example when we declare `String? name;` default value of `name` is `null` and can be changed.

But we cannot  declare `String name;` you have to give value while declaring like `String name = 'Funny Name';` ensuring that value of   `name` can never be null.

Here use `!` mark after the variable to tell the compiler that value of `user.profilePhotoUrl` is not null like `user.profilePhotoUrl!`

My suggestion is to use `String` intead of `String?` in that case you don't need to use `!`

Answer (score 0):

we should always handle null value case first. Here if in case a the value of "profilePhotoUrl" is equal to null then we have handle it with this default link which is after ?? 'any other link'.

```
Container(
              width: 54,
              height: 54,
              decoration:BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                    user.profilePhotoUrl ?? 'any other link',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Here is an example :
In below example i haven't provided any value to profilePhotoUrl and declared it as nullable & so when it execute it will get null but as we have handle it already using null operator.

**??
Called also null operator. This operator returns expression on its left, except if it is null, and if so, it returns right expression:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  
  String? profilePhotoUrl;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
              width: 350,
              height: 450,
              decoration:BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                    profilePhotoUrl ?? 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
  }
}
```

**What are ??, ??=, ?., …? in Dart?**
https://jelenaaa.medium.com/what-are-in-dart-df1f11706dd6